# Fourier transform or expression for $n$-th root of $sin(x)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

This morning I asked a question about functional square root. On the [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root) page of it, I found it interesting that the $n$-th root of $sin(x)$ looks like a triangle wave as $n$ goes to infinity. Is there a special Fourier transform of $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{sin(x)}$, or a nice way to formulate this wave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it itself (green), over half a period, is the [Triangular, hat, or tent function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function), a convolution of two unit rectangular (boxcar) functions, and thus the Fourier transform of the *square* of the [Sinc , normalized cardinal sine, function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).

Signal processing engineers prefer its cousin, the [Sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave).